# Update Database with Adobe Flash

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript

I have trouble to edit data in my database (MySQL).
I try to edit data with Flash (.swf)
Here is the flow of my program
Data -> Edit data with flash -> Data updated

My PHP script

```
<?php

mysql_pconnect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("adaptasi");

$qResult = mysql_query ('UPDATE materi
        SET isi = "????"
        WHERE id = 1');

$rString ="";

echo "edit=".$rString;

?>
```

and my Actionscript for flash

```
var result:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

var edit:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

var filepath:String;

result.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) { 
    if (success) { 
        text_morfologi.text = result.result;
        trace("success");
    } else { 
      trace('error...');
    } 
}; 

filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
result.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", result, "GET");

btnedit.setStyle("fontSize", 22);
btnsave.setStyle("fontSize", 22);

btnedit.visible = true;
btnedit.onRelease = function() {
    text_morfologi.type = "input";
    btnedit.visible = false;
    btnsave.visible = true;
}

btnsave.onRelease = function() {
    edit.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
        if (success) {
            text_morfologi.text = edit.edit;
            trace("success");
            } else {
                trace('error...');
        } 
}; 

filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
edit.sendAndLoad(filepath + "editmorfologi.php", edit, "GET");

    btnedit.visible = true;
    btnsave.visible = false;
    output.text = "data berhasil diubah...";
}
```

I can execute that script from flash. But I don't know what should I insert into SET in SQL Update...

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; please use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: You should know that the SQL UPDATE statement didn't work as the SELECT one, for more details, take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp), also for APIs used to connect to MySQL, "mysql" extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7, so you should think to use "mysqli" or "PDO" extensions, for more about that, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) ...

Comment: I can execute that. And the answer is how to load input from flash to the SET in the Update query?

Comment: You have to send your data using the `LoadVars` object, take a look on the example in this [page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001174.html) ...

Comment: And what should I write in the PHP script, in SET query?

Comment: You can get the sent data using the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) arrays according to the method using to send it in your AS2 code, for more take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp) ...

Comment: Can you write me the PHP Script for my trouble

Comment: Don't be hurried, you have what you need as doc, take your time and try to do it, then if you still have problems, you can post your code and others (me included) will sure help you ... The problem is not about writing code, it's about understanding it and how it's working ... take your time and do it ...

Comment: &errorcode=3&msg=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM materi SET (NULL, '') WHERE id = 1' at line 1

Comment: I have error like that.

Comment: An SQL UPDATE statement can be like this, for example : `UPDATE users SET name = 'new name' WHERE id = 15;` ...

Comment: &errorcode=3&msg=Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: and Undefined index: materi in C:\xampp\htdocs\adaptasi\editmorfologi.php on line 6